# implement partitioning on PostgreSQL tables

Tags: partitioning, postgresql-12

I'm implementing partition to PostgreSQL (version 12). I'll use the transaction_date (year) to create the partitions, one partition per year, trigger and function to save data on the right partition.

I'm applying the implementation Using Inheritance and how can I load the partitions for 2009, 2010, 2011, ...?

All the examples I found starts with an empty table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> *I'm applying the implementation Using Inheritance*

Don't do that.

With Postgres 12, you should use [declarative partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) which also doesn't require the use of triggers.

```sql
create table your_table
(
  ..., 
  transaction_date timestamp not null
)
partition by range (transaction_date);

create table your_table_p2018
  partition of your_table
  for values from ('2018-01-01') to ('2019-01-01');

create table your_table_p2019
  partition of your_table
  for values from ('2019-01-01') to ('2020-01-01');

create table your_table_p2020
  partition of your_table
  for values from ('2020-01-01') to ('2021-01-01');
```

An insert into `your_table` will automatically be routed into the appropriate partition.

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name, this implementation I know, my point here is how to implement partition starting from an existing and populated table, how to move the data o the right partition?

Comment: You can't turn an existing table into a partitioned table. Except if the existing table would be exactly one partition of the new partitioned table